# why does ifstream read beyond eof? (even if no file is open) how to stop reading at eof?

Tags: c++, io, fstream, ifstream, eof

i was just testing some io safe checks with fstream and noticed i don't get any flags when seeking outside (i expected eof, but i realize flags are only set after io operations?) and when trying to read beyond the file size, i expected it to stop at eof, but it keeps on reading in from some unknown source. and lastly i noticed you don't even need to open a file. do i have to manually apply the math myself so it doesn't read past eof? and how/why/where is it reading past the file?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void checkErrors(std::ifstream& f){
    std::cout<<"FLAGS: ";
    if(f.good()) std::cout<<"good";
    if(f.rdstate() & f.badbit) std::cout<<"badbit ";
    if(f.rdstate() & f.eofbit) std::cout<<"eofbit ";
    if(f.rdstate() & f.failbit) std::cout<<"failbit ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

int main(){
    std::ifstream file;
//  file.open("abc.txt"); // don't even have to open any file

    file.seekg(100, file.beg); // can seek outside file
    std::cout<<file.tellg()<<std::endl; // 100 (if open else) -1
    checkErrors(file); // FLAGS: good (if open else) failbit

    int size = 200;
    char* data = new char[size];

    file.read(data,size); // can read outside file
    checkErrors(file); // FLAGS: eofbit failbit (if open else) failbit

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)std::cout<<data[i]; // PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\...

}
```

Comment: Either instruct the stream to throw when a failure bit is set via `file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit);`, or check the state of the stream before performing operations like `seekg`. As it stands, you have undefined behavior.

Comment: Welcome to undefined behavior land.  You are violating the contract so anything can happen.  What you need to do is seek only do these operations if the file successfully opened, and then you can seek to the end with `file.seekg(0, file.end);` and use `tellg` to get the size you can read.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks, but i know how to open a file and get the size. i can still read way past the eof. all this text of paths get read in. i'm just wondering if that's meant to happen? and if i must check how much space is left myself?

Comment: `seekg` doesn't check the provided input, that's your job.  If you give it bad input, then whatever you get out of it is what you get.  You have undefined behavior if you give it bad values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why does ifstream read beyond eof?

I am sure it does not.
Are you asking why the `bad()` is not true after you move beyond the end?

> (even if no file is open) how to stop reading at eof?

If you attempt to read beyond the end of a file then you will get an error. Moving beyond the end by itself is not enough. But an attempt to access the data after you are beyond the end should cause an error.

Well you see to have a bug is here:

```
file.read(data,size); // can read outside file
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)std::cout<<data[i]; // PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\...
```

This should be written as:

```
if (file.read(data, size)) {
    // If you attempt to read and it works then you can print out
    // the data you read otherwise what is the point.

    // Also notice you can't gurantee that you got `size` bytes.
    // You should consult `gcount()` to get the number of characters read.

    for(int i = 0; i < file.gcount(); ++i) {
        std::cout << data[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. i literally just checked and gcount returned 0. i commented out the read and realized i still have all that text. lol (silly me)

Comment: hey again, about the "you can't guarantee that you got `size` bytes" that'd just be if you used `readsome` wouldn't it. according to both [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) and [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) it'll either read all the chars otherwise eofbit and failbit will be set. which means you'd have to go into the `else` of the above if statement if you want to try use whatever amount it did read.

Comment: @Puddle You are correct. I don't often use the raw `read()` into byte arrays I am more used to using `std::string` so I missed that. My if statement would look like this: `if (std::getline(file, string))` as this will read up to but not past the end of the file (and thus not setting the bad flags). Making this extra check unnecessary.